# Ableton-like Warping in a VST?

Tags: recordings

I use FL Studio, and the one thing I miss is Ableton's Warping feature.

I've looked at Newtone, but I don't really find it suitable for what I want to do, which is take full tracks that were recorded on tape, and warp them to tighten them up to a grid.

Are there any third party VSTs which are intuitive and powerful as Ableton to handle longer tracks (5 or 6 minutes)